# Does C# have runtime-assigned goto?

Tags: c#, .net, goto

I am creating a C# program in which I would like to use goto, but not to a compile-time constant, ie. to use a string as a label identifier.

```cs
top:

string label = "top";
// Doesn't work
goto label;

// Doesn't work either
goto "top";
```

I am aware that `goto` is not a good programming practise, and this isn't an opinion question on whether one should use it in an application – it's for a program which generates C# code from BASIC, which has computed goto.

Comment: it doesn't have it

Comment: i think you can achieve the same behavior by using a dictionary of functions to allow you to dispatch to some code by string value. of course there would be some major challenges dealing with variables and stuff.

Comment: That's a really good idea, thank you! You could keep a Dictionary<int, Action> of the line numbers and jump to them, essentially giving computed goto. If you want to post an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: does BASIC only support goto line number? if that's the case maybe there's a simpler way such as the answer Jon Skeet posted.

Comment: The version I was going to transpile has a potentially infinite/very high no. of line numbers, and you can jump to one with a user-input based calculation or something, essentially goto an int variable. The issue I saw with Jon's switch case is if the program was 300 lines, would there have to be 300 cases, and you generate the switch case every time the user has a goto in their code?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a link to the documentation for a _computed goto_ in BASIC or some other language so that we are exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is that “computed” as in an `ON`...`GOTO` construct, where there's an explicit list of line numbers, or like in Atari BASIC where you could use arbitrary numeric expressions as GOTO targets, like `GOTO 1000*N`?

Comment: I was looking for what you described as Atari BASIC's gotos. In my mind was Sinclair BASIC, but I don't have an exact spec to link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please note that C# example code below is intended specifically for use as the output format of a BASIC-to-C# compiler.  Anyone who writes “real” C# code like this shall have their programming license revoked.**

BASIC's GOTO statement can be implemented using “tail call pessimization”: Transform every `GOTO X` to `GOSUB X:RETURN`.

You can then render your entire BASIC program as one giant `Gosub(int lineNumber)` function, using a switch statement with a `case` block for each line number, with a `Main` function that simply GOSUBs to the lowest line number.

So, for example, the BASIC program:

```
10 PRINT "Enter an integer: ";
20 INPUT N%
30 IF N% MOD 2 = 0 THEN GOTO 60
40 PRINT N%;" is odd."
50 GOTO 70
60 PRINT N%;" is even."
70 PRINT "Goodbye."
```

can be converted line-by-line into a C# program like this:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    // BASIC variables are always global and zero-initialized.
    static int n_int = 0;

    static void Gosub(int lineNumber)
    {
        switch (lineNumber)
        {
            case 10: // 10 PRINT "Enter an integer: ";N%
                Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
                // By default, the end of each line falls thru to next line number
                goto case 20;
            case 20: // 20 INPUT N%
                n_int = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                goto case 30;
            case 30: // 30 IF N% MOD 2 = 0 THEN GOTO 60
                if (n_int % 2 == 0)
                {
                    Gosub(60);
                    return;
                }
                goto case 40;
            case 40: // 40 PRINT N%;" is odd."
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is odd.", n_int);
                goto case 50;
            case 50: // 50 GOTO 70
                Gosub(70);
                return;
            case 60: // 60 PRINT N%;" is even."
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is even.", n_int);
                goto case 70;
            case 70: // 70 PRINT "Goodbye."
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
                // Falling off the end of the program exits it.
                return;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Gosub(10);
    }
}
```

When you have a literal line number like this, you can optimize `Gosub(X); return;` to `goto case X;`.  However, the function call approach allows the line number to be an arbitrary expression, which C#'s `goto case` does not.

The converted code obviously isn't very maintainable, but it does compile and run.

**Edit**: Apparently, the C# compiler doesn't guarantee tail call optimization, which may cause a stack overflow for long or infinite loops.  However, you can perform this optimization manually by re-assigning the `lineNumber` parameter and jumping back to the start of the `switch` statement, like this:

```
using System;

static class Program
{
    // BASIC variables are always global and zero-initialized.
    static int n_int = 0;

    static void Gosub(int lineNumber)
    {
        START:
        switch (lineNumber)
        {
            case 10: // 10 PRINT "Enter an integer: ";N%
                Console.Write("Enter an integer: ");
                // By default, the end of each line falls thru to next line number
                goto case 20;
            case 20: // 20 INPUT N%
                n_int = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                goto case 30;
            case 30: // 30 IF N% MOD 2 = 0 THEN GOTO 60
                if (n_int % 2 == 0)
                {
                    lineNumber = 60;
                    goto START;
                }
                goto case 40;
            case 40: // 40 PRINT N%;" is odd."
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is odd.", n_int);
                goto case 50;
            case 50: // 50 GOTO 70
                lineNumber = 70;
                goto START;
            case 60: // 60 PRINT N%;" is even."
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is even.", n_int);
                goto case 70;
            case 70: // 70 PRINT "Goodbye."
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye.");
                // Falling off the end of the program exits it.
                return;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Gosub(10);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

As in the previous example, a *constant* `GOTO` target can be optimized into a single `goto case` statement.

Comment: Genius! My only thoughts about these are gotos within blocks like, say, within a for/if. I suppose if you didn’t allow jumping out of or into a block you could have a nested function within the for loop’s switch case?

Comment: Well, a `FOR`...`NEXT` loop can be easily transformed into a `WHILE`...`WEND` loop, which can then be transformed into `GOTO` plus `IF`...`GOTO`.  There may still be some weird edge cases jumping into or out of a loop.

Comment: Ok so this lead to another problem. A simple program such as 10 Print "Hello" 11 goto 10. (Which compiles to a series of Gosub(10)) causes a StackOverflowException due to a huge ammount of recursion. I'm not sure if this is fixable? Sometimes it is required for BASIC programs to have infinite loops, eg. for games.

Comment: Well, as I already mentioned in my answer, if a BASIC `GOTO` target is constant, you can always optimize it into a straightforward `goto case` statement.  It's only *computed* `GOTO` (and `GOSUB`) that will require a `Gosub` call.  And since line-numbered BASIC has no local variables, stack frames will be relatively cheap.

Comment: Thanks. I have also realised that if you run csc with /optimize , the stack does not overflow. Likely because of what you mention at the start of your edit. However, I think I will still attempt to optimise constant and infinite goto calls myself, just because they are so common.

Answer (score 10):

No, there's nothing like this. If you really, really need this, I'd probably generate a switch statement:

```
switch (label):
{
    case "top":
        goto top;
    case "bottom":
        goto bottom;
    // ...
}
```

If you *can* break the code into actions with a `Dictionary<string, Action>`, that would be cleaner code to look at afterwards... but if you need locals to be in scope etc, then this "nasty" code may be a simpler way to mimic the BASIC behaviour.